# Class Not Found : KafkaRDDPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark Standalone v 2.1.0 cluster, and I have a park streaming application under eclipse maven. I want to deploy it on the cluster. Eclipse displays this exeption:

[image]

@JacekLaskowski J'ai  les dependence comme suit  :

```
 <!--  Dependence Scala 2.11.8  -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>

<!--  Dependence Spark 2.1.0 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- kafka  --> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
```

Comment: How did you define the Spark Streaming application's dependencies?  You should really `spark-submit` your Spark application to the cluster.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski J'ai  les dependence comme suit  :